# Number of possible Venn diagrams given the cardinalities of the sets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Consider $n$ sets with respective cardinalities $c_1$, $\ldots$, $c_n$. How many possible Venn diagrams of these set are there? I didn't find with Google.